# Non-axiomatisability and ultraproducts

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a first-order theory over a language $L$, and let $\mathcal{M}$ be a subclass of the class of models of $T$. As I understand it, if there is no theory $\hat{T}$ over $L$ whose class of models is exactly $\mathcal{M}$, frequently, the "morally correct" reason is that $\mathcal{M}$ is not closed under ultraproducts. However, it is sometimes possible to obtain a simpler proof of non-axiomatisability by compactness or completeness considerations.

**Example**. Consider the first order theory of fields, and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the class of fields of positive characteristic. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is not axiomatisable in the language of fields since, for example, if we take the ultraproduct of all the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ prime, we would obtain a field of characteristic 0.

We could also prove this directly: if $T'$ is the naïve axiomatisation of fields of characteristic 0 (i.e. the one with one axiom of the form $\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{n\text{ times}} \ne 0$ for every positive $n \in \mathbb{N}$), and $\hat{T}$ is any axiomatisation of $\mathcal{M}$, then $T' \cup \hat{T}$ is inconsistent, so there is some finite subset which is inconsistent, so there is some finite set $X$ for which $\hat{T}$ proves that there is an $n \in X$ such that $\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{n\text{ times}} = 0$; but there are fields of positive characteristic other than those $n \in X$ — a contradiction.

**Question**. Is it in fact *always* possible to translate a proof of non-axiomatisability using ultraproducts to one using compactness/completeness?

Comment: I couldn't prove that non-abelian simple groups aren't axiomatizable without using ultraproducts on the relevant example sheet, and neither could my supervisor. (By the way, it's sort of funny that you call the second proof "direct." The most direct proof I know of the compactness theorem is using ultraproducts.)

Comment: By the way, it is in fact a (difficult) theorem that $M$ is axiomatizable _if and only if_ it is closed under ultraproducts. See, for example, Chapter 6 of Pete Clark's notes on model theory: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/MATH8900.html

Comment: @Qiaochu: so difficult it's not true. For example, take T a theory in a countable language with infinite models, and M an uncountable model of T. Then the class of structures formable from M by repeatedly taking ultraproducts contains only uncountable structures, so can't be axiomatizable by downward Lowenheim-Skolem.

Comment: @Qiaochu: there's a correct version of this result in Chang and Keisler's Model Theory (1990 edition): a class of structures is axiomatizable iff it's closed under ultraproducts and isomorphisms, and its complement is closed under ultrapowers.

Comment: @Chris: huh. Seems I misread something. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I think we have the same supervisor, and I think it's your solution he cites in his notes on the problems. I personally think the "real" reason for compactness is completeness (and finiteness of proofs), even if the proof by ultraproducts is more direct or even more "morally correct". Incidentally, he makes a similar, if weaker, claim in his textbook: "A formula is equivalent to a first-order formula if and only if its class of models is closed under ultraproducts."

Answer (score 3):

To start with, here is a **conditional** negative answer *(really any compact proper extension of $\mathsf{FOL}$ can get the ball rolling, but this is a really cool one)*:

> If we add the ability to quantify over isomorphisms of ordered fields in a precise sense we get a compact logic $\mathcal{L}(Q_\mathsf{Of})$; see [Mekler/Shelah 1993](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9301204.pdf). The class $\mathfrak{K}$ of rigid ordered fields is $\mathcal{L}(Q_{\mathsf{Of}})$-definable, so its non-elementarity (= non-$\mathsf{FOL}$-definability) cannot be ruled out purely on compactness grounds. Moreover, all nontrivial ultraproducts over $\omega$ are countably saturated, so assuming $\mathsf{CH}$ any nontrivial ultraproduct over $\omega$ of the rigid ordered field $\mathbb{Q}$ must be non-rigid (being countably saturated and of size $\aleph_1$). So **conditionally on $\mathsf{CH}$** we have simple negative answer to your question: the non-elementarity of $\mathfrak{K}$ cannot be established by compactness alone, but can be established using ultrapowers.

OK, now let's think about getting rid of $\mathsf{CH}$ ...

One immediate idea is to use an **absoluteness theorem**. Specifically, the sentence

> $(*)\quad $ "There is a *countable* non-rigid ordered field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$"

is $\Sigma^1_1$, and by the argument above **plus downward Lowenheim-Skolem** we know that $(*)$ follows from $\mathsf{CH}$. [Mostowski absoluteness](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165762/absolutness-of-pi-11-statements) then gives us $(*)$ unconditionally.

But there's a serious drawback to this approach (besides the obvious one of "but *why* though?"). The appearance of downward Lowenheim-Skolem should actually be very disappointing. [Lindstrom's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem) says that first-order logic is maximal with respect to compactness and (a very weak form of) downward Lowenheim-Skolem. Consequently, in some sense any non-axiomatizability fact is a purely abstract consequence of compactness and downward Lowenheim-Skolem. So if we want to build a situation where ultraproducts suffice and compactness alone doesn't, we should avoid Lowenheim-Skolem.

It seems more reasonable, therefore, to try to prove directly in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\mathbb{Q}$ has a non-rigid ultrapower. There's a big theorem which lets us do this in one line: non-rigidity is upwards-preserved by ultrapowers, so apply [Keisler-Shelah](https://shelah.logic.at/files/95368/13.pdf) given some non-rigid ordered field $F\equiv \mathbb{Q}$. Of course, even if we're okay bringing a big theorem like KS into the picture, there's still the issue of how we get such an $F$ in the first place. Put another way, it's neat that the sentence

> $(\dagger)\quad$ "Every infinite structure has a non-rigid ultrapower"

can be proved in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by appeal to the properties of first-order logic, but that limits the satisfyingness of $(\dagger)$ for our purposes here. So we plausibly have an unconditional ultraproduct-only *construction*, but in terms of an *argument* we still haven't gotten very far.

All of this raises the following follow-up question:

> Can $\mathsf{ZFC}$ prove (without bringing first-order model theory into the picture) that every countably infinite structure in a countable language has a non-rigid ultrapower over $\omega$?

Embarrassingly, even if we ignore the parenthetical **this isn't obvious to me** (and indeed Shelah has a number of papers on the subtleties of $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provable facts about ultrapowers, such as the ["Vive la difference" series](https://shelah.logic.at/files/130108/vive.pdf))! But surely I'm having a silly moment and someone will point out what I'm missing in a comment below ... (EDIT: I've now [asked this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293034/non-rigid-ultrapowers-in-mathsfzfc) as a separate question.)

Comment: The Mekler-Shelah paper you linked to is actually from 1993 (in fact, Mekler died in 1992). The 2021 date on the pdf just comes from arXiv recompiling the source when someone accesses the paper for the first time in a while.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oops, how embarrassing - fixed, thanks!