# Non-rigid ultrapowers in $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters

This question stems from a weakness in [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3569736/28111).

> **Question**: Can $\mathsf{ZFC}$ prove, without invoking first-order model theory, that for every countably infinite structure $\mathcal{A}$ in a countable language there is an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$ such that the ultrapower $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{U}$ has a nontrivial automorphism?

"Obviously" the answer is yes! *(... right?)*

Note that this is trivial in $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$: $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone proves that any nontrivial ultrapower is countably saturated, which in the presence of $\mathsf{CH}$ lets us run a back-and-forth argument to show that $\mathcal{A}^\mathcal{U}$ is non-rigid whenever $\mathcal{A}$ is countable and $\mathcal{U}$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$. Separately, note that if we drop *both* the model theory prohibition and the requirement that the ultrafilter be on $\omega$ a positive answer follows from the Keisler-Shelah theorem, but $(i)$ that doesn't count and $(ii)$ [$\mathsf{ZFC}$ can't bring down KS to $\omega$ as one might expect](https://shelah.logic.at/files/130108/vive.pdf), so it ultimately doesn't seem like a promising direction.

I strongly suspect that I'm missing  a very simple argument, but at present I'm not seeing it.

*Now [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408178/non-rigid-ultrapowers-in-mathsfzfc).*